# ¿Qué es una interfaz en Java y cuáles son sus características o atributos?

Tags: java

¿Qué es una interfaz en Java y cuáles son sus características o atributos?

Comment: http://www.mundojava.net/interfaces.html?Pg=java_inicial_4_5.html

Answer (score 10):

Una interfaz suele ser útil para cuando tienes que trabajar sobre un mismo producto de distintos fabricantes, o cuando tienes que trabajar en grupo, o quieres tener varios tipos de objetos que comparten muchas de sus características.

Podrías tener entonces una interfaz común para `Impresora` con [métodos abstractos](http://puntocomnoesunlenguaje.blogspot.com/2012/07/metodo-abstracto.html):

Métodos: `imprimir();`, `escanear();`, `copiar();` etc.

```
public interface Impresora{

    public abstract imprimir();

    public abstract escanear();

    public abstract copiar();     

}
```

Y luego además, podrías tener clases respectivas para distintas impresoras como:

```
public class Canon extends Impresora{ //implementación }

public class Epson extends Impresora{ //implementación }

public class Samsung extends Impresora{  //implementacion  }
```

De esta manera te aseguras que todas las clases tengan los métodos `imprimir();` `escanear();` y `copiar();`

Después para usarlas podrías hacer lo siguiente.

```
import Impresora;

public static void main(String args[]){

    Impresora impresora1 = new Canon();

    impresora1.imprimir(); //De esta manera usas el imprimir de Canon.       


}
```

> ## ¿Por que debería de usar interfaces?

- ## Facilitan el trabajo en equipo y *modularizan* el código.

Cada fabricante tiene sus propias [librerías](https://aprende-web.net/librerias/) para sus productos y usando interfaces facilitas tanto el trabajo en equipo cuando tengas que trabajar en equipo.

- ## Ayudan al mantenimiento del código

También es útil para mantener el código a *posteriori*, si actualizan las librerías de un fabricante tan solo deberás actualizar una clase y te será mucho más fácil.

- ## Facilitan el uso del código

  O usar las mismas constantes para tratar tus objetos de forma independiente.

Personalmente para mí esas son las mayores ventajas que trae, entre otras cuantas que ahora mismo no sabría mencionarte.

Answer (score 3):

las interfaces (interface) en java son un modo de realizar herencia, son muy útiles para poder minimizar la escritura de código y tener el comportamiento de ciertos objetos definidos (obliga al objeto implementar dicho comportamiento) de acuerdo al tipo de solución que tengas, también es importante recordar que puedes hacer que una clase en java pueda implementar mas de una interface al mismo tiempo, otra manera de realizar herencia en java es usar puntos de extensión (extends) pero eso es otra historia.

Realmente son muy útiles, te recomiendo que sigas practicando.

Un ejemplo sencillo, tenemos un programa que realiza saludos en diferentes idiomas, usando una interface abstraemos el comportamiento en común de todos los idiomas en este caso todos los idomas "saludan" entonces definimos ese comportamiento en una interface y garantizamos que todos los demás objetos que hereden de nuestra interface se vean obligados a implementar un saludo de manera particular, en el caso de "italiano" y "english" que implementan "idioma" se ven obligados a implementar el método "saludo", también en java es importante resaltar la etiqueta @Override para indicar que es un método que esta siendo escrito de forma particular en la clase.

```
public interface Idioma {
   public void saludar();
}
public class Italiano implements Idioma {
   @Override
   public void saludar() {
       System.out.println("Chao");
   }
}
public class English implements idioma {
   @Override
   public void saludar() {
      System.out.println("Hello");
   }
}
```

Bueno, espero te haya servido.

Answer (score 1):

Su importancia se debe a que con extends solo se puede heredar de una clase a la ves,
pero puedes implementar todas la interfaces que quieras(he visto clases con mas de 20 interfaces implementadas, no hay un limite).

***aqui te dejo el ejemplo con el que yo aprendi este tema:***

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8xF_BSpSATw&t=0s&list=PLU8oAlHdN5BktAXdEVCLUYzvDyqRQJ2lk&index=50][1] 
***Si quieres saber mas acerca del ejemplo porfavor mira esta secuencia de videos impartida por un excelente profesor***

El metodo compareTo(), me ordenaba un array de empleados de menor a mayor sueldo, el unico codigo que ingrese dentro del metodo fue para personalizarlo y esto no es dificil ya que en la api de java, donde esta el metodo, este trae una guia de lo que hice alli.

```
class Empleado implements Comparable, Trabajadores{     

@Override
    public int compareTo(Object miObj) {

        Empleado other = (Empleado) miObj;

        if (this.sueldo < other.sueldo) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (this.sueldo < other.sueldo) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    private final String nombre;

    private double sueldo;

    private Date altaContrato;
}
```

---

---